# Could you explain how does the 俺が作り上げたのではないことは and the でもない work here?

Tags: meaning

> 俺が作り上げたのではないことは、昨日の行動からして自分が夢遊病だったり第二人格でもないと無理なのは解っている。

Could you explain how does the 俺が作り上げたのではないことは and the でもない work here.

I guess it's
"I fact that I didn't make it up"

As for the でもない I guess it's like

Judging from my conduct yesterday it's neither due to sleepwalking nor a second personality.

Can someone correct me on this?

Comment: This translation is right.

Comment: @TakahiroWaki "I fact that I didn't make it up" makes no sense, so I can't see how it could be right. "It's a fact that I didn't make it up" perhaps, but that doesn't take into account that it's the topic, either.

Comment: I thought "It's a fact",too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sentence is certainly confusing, but I would parse this as a sentence with two long topics marked with the two は. This sentence can be safely divided into two sentences:

> - 【俺が作り上げたのではないこと】は解っている。
>     I know that it was not something made by me.
> - 【（昨日の行動からして）（自分が夢遊病だったり第二人格でもないと）無理なの】は解っている。
>     Judging from what I did yesterday, I know that it (=making it) was impossible, unless I were a noctambulist or had a second personality.
>
> <sub>The topic (noun phrase) is marked with 【】)</sub>

Comment: 「『俺が作り上げたのではない』っていうシナリオ/仮説は、俺が夢遊病か二重人格でもない限りありえない/成り立たない。」っていう意味かと思ったんですけど・・「夢遊病でも二重人格でもないので、俺が作り上げたんじゃないっていうことは証明できない」みたいな・・・

Comment: @chocolate え、それだと「俺が夢遊病であれば、俺が造り上げたのではないという仮定も成り立ちうる」（つまり俺が夢遊病ではない以上、これは俺が作ったものに決まっている）ということになって、多分意図している意味とは逆になるような…（混乱してきた）

Comment: こんな感じの話どっかで読んだような気がします・・「『俺は話をでっち上げてるんじゃなくて、実際にそれを知っているんだ、だからこれは事実なんだ』っていうことは、俺が夢遊病か何か‌​で夜中にそこに行って見てきたのでもない限り、あり‌​えない・信じてもらえない」って感じの話だ‌​ったような・・（「第二人格」がどう絡んで‌​くるかちょっとわかんないですけど）`つまり俺が夢遊病ではない以上、これ‌​は俺が作ったものに決まっている` <- 夢遊病じゃないので、みんなに「お前の作り話に決まっている！」って思われてしまうのは仕方ないとわかっている、って感じで。。

Answer (score 0):

That sentence is poorly composed and doesn't make much sense, though you can imagine that it actually wanted to say 俺が作り上げたのではないことは、昨日の行動からして  **明らかで、**自分が夢遊病だったり第二人格でもないと無理なのは解っている or "It's obvious from what I did yesterday that I didn't make it up and I know it's impossible unless I was a sleepwalker or in another personality or so".